# ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Hwnd crash

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, office-interop, window-handles

I'm using `ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Hwnd` to get the handle of the active document Window in MS Word, but it does crash in Word 2007. I tried using long instead of int, tried to catch the exception but no exception is thrown.

```
Public WithEvents wa As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
wa = HostApplication

    Public Function getWindowHWND() As Integer
        Try
            getWindowHWND = wa.ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Hwnd
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(1)
            getWindowHWND = -1
        Finally
        End Try
    End Function
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug? How can I get the handle in an equivalent way if it's not fixable? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does it crash so hard your application stops? Possibly something in the event log?

Comment: yes, it's an MS Word plugin and MS Word crashes hard.

Comment: IIRC, the `HWnd` Property is available from 2013. Unfortunatly, the Office documentation doesn't show the Document Model version when a Property/Method was implemented, since it applies to VBA, where you can *see it*. COM interop apparently doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No such property exist in Word 2007.

Since Word 2013 you could use the `Hwnd` property of `Window` that is exposed from the `Application` object:

```
var windowHandle = wordApplication.ActiveWindow.Hwnd;
```

There is no need to use the `ActiveDocument` property in the middle. This fails when no document is open.

In earlier Word versions you could use the `Process` class from the .NET BCL to retrieve the main window handle, for example:

```
  var word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application(); 
  word.Visible = true; 
  word.Activate();
  word.Application.Caption = "My Word";

  foreach( Process p in Process.GetProcessesByName( "winword" ) )
  {
    if( p.MainWindowTitle == "My Word" )
    {
      Debug.WriteLine( p.Handle.ToString() );
    }
  }
```